# GraalVM native image of JCEF application not working, even if agent generated config files were added

Tags: java, chromium-embedded, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have created a browser based on jcef that displays any url passed to it in command line with some custom context menu, using the library [jcefmaven](https://github.com/jcefmaven/jcefmaven) (The jcef native are stored in a fat jar and extracted if not present). I generated the config files using the native image agent. when i tried to build a native image of a jar with those config files, I get two warnings `Warning: Method org.cef.browser.CefBrowserWr$3.coalesceEvents(AWTEvent, AWTEvent) not found.` and `Warning: Method org.example.SingletonDevTools.coalesceEvents(AWTEvent, AWTEvent) not found.`even if reflect-config.json does contain the following entries:

```
{
  "name":"org.cef.browser.CefBrowserWr$3",
  "methods":[{"name":"coalesceEvents","parameterTypes":["java.awt.AWTEvent","java.awt.AWTEvent"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.example.SingletonDevTools",
  "methods":[{"name":"coalesceEvents","parameterTypes":["java.awt.AWTEvent","java.awt.AWTEvent"] }]
}
```

and when I launch the native image with same parameters and conditions as the config generation, I get the following error:

```
Launch called
Nov 22, 2023 10:37:35 AM me.friwi.jcefmaven.impl.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler handleProgress
INFO: LOCATING |> In progress...
Nov 22, 2023 10:37:35 AM me.friwi.jcefmaven.impl.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler handleProgress
INFO: INITIALIZING |> In progress...
Nov 22, 2023 10:37:35 AM me.friwi.jcefmaven.impl.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler handleProgress
INFO: INITIALIZED |> In progress...
initialize on Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] with library path /home/****/****/****/jcef-bundle
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0": java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cef.callback.CefCommandLine_N
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:133)
    at org.cef.CefApp.N_Initialize(Native Method)
    at org.cef.CefApp.access$400(CefApp.java:25)
    at org.cef.CefApp$3.run(CefApp.java:427)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:308)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:171)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:807)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:210)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0": java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cef.callback.CefSchemeRegistrar_N
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:133)
    at org.cef.CefApp.N_Initialize(Native Method)
    at org.cef.CefApp.access$400(CefApp.java:25)
    at org.cef.CefApp$3.run(CefApp.java:427)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:308)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:171)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop@17.0.9/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:807)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:210)
[1122/103735.075523:WARNING:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(88)] Could not create policy manager as CBCM is not enabled.
[1122/103735.158443:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(393)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Exception in thread "System-13": java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cef.browser.CefFrame_N
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:133)
Exception in thread "System-13": java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cef.network.CefRequest_N
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:133)
Exception in thread "System-19": java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cef.misc.BoolRef
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:133)
Exception in thread "System-142": java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cef.callback.CefContextMenuParams_N
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:133)
Exception in thread "System-142": java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cef.callback.CefMenuModel_N
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:133)
Exception in thread "System-142": java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.example.ContextMenuHandler.onBeforeContextMenu(ContextMenuHandler.java:30)
    at org.cef.CefClient.onBeforeContextMenu(CefClient.java:246)
```

OS :- Linux Mint

Java version: 17

## Source Code :-

**SingletonDevTools.java**

```
public class SingletonDevTools extends JFrame {
    private static SingletonDevTools instance;

    private SingletonDevTools(){
        super("Dev Tools");
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static SingletonDevTools getInstance(){
        if(instance == null || !instance.isDisplayable()) {
            instance = new SingletonDevTools();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void launch(CefBrowser devToolsBrowser) {
        if(!isVisible()){
            getContentPane().add(devToolsBrowser.getUIComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setVisible(true);
        } else {
            toFront();
        }
    }
}
```

**ContextMenuHandler.java**

```
public class ContextMenuHandler extends CefContextMenuHandlerAdapter {
    private final int INSPECT = 1;
    private final int OPEN_IN_BROWSER = 2;
    private final int RELOAD = 3;
    String url;
    private CefBrowser devTools;
    private CefBrowser browser;

    public ContextMenuHandler(CefBrowser browser, String url) {
        this.devTools = browser.getDevTools();
        this.browser = browser;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeforeContextMenu(
            CefBrowser browser, CefFrame frame, CefContextMenuParams params, CefMenuModel model
    ) {
        // Clear the default context menu
        model.clear();

        // Add a custom menu item
        model.addItem(RELOAD, "Reload");
        model.setEnabled(RELOAD, true);

        model.addSeparator();

        model.addItem(INSPECT, "Inspect");
        model.setEnabled(INSPECT, true);

        model.addItem(OPEN_IN_BROWSER, "Open in browser");
        model.setEnabled(OPEN_IN_BROWSER, true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextMenuCommand(CefBrowser browser, CefFrame frame,
                                        CefContextMenuParams params, int commandId, int eventFlags
    ) {
        // Register a listener for custom menu item clicks
        switch (commandId) {
            case RELOAD -> {
                browser.reload();
                return true;
            }
            case INSPECT -> {
                SingletonDevTools.getInstance().launch(devTools);
                return true;
            }
            case OPEN_IN_BROWSER -> {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

**JcefLauncher.java**

```
public class JcefLauncher {
    String url;
    CefApp app;

    public JcefLauncher(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void launch() {
        System.out.println("Launch called");
        //Create a new CefAppBuilder instance
        CefAppBuilder builder = new CefAppBuilder();

        //Configure the builder instance
        builder.getCefSettings().windowless_rendering_enabled = false;

        //Build a CefApp instance using the configuration above
        try {
            app = builder.build();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | CefInitializationException | UnsupportedPlatformException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Create a CefClient instance
        CefClient client = app.createClient();

        // Create a CefBrowser instance
        CefBrowser browser = client.createBrowser(this.url, false, false);

        final ContextMenuHandler contextMenuHandler = new ContextMenuHandler(browser, this.url);
        client.addContextMenuHandler(contextMenuHandler);

        client.addDisplayHandler(new CefDisplayHandlerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAddressChange(CefBrowser browser, CefFrame frame, String url) {
                contextMenuHandler.setUrl(url);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(CefBrowser browser, CefSettings.LogSeverity level, String message, String source, int line){
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Create a JFrame to host the browser
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Time Table Scheduler");
        frame.setSize(1260, 700);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(browser.getUIComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                app.dispose();
                System.out.println("System exiting");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            if (!frame.isVisible()){
                app.dispose();
                System.out.println("System exiting");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args == null || args.length==0) {
            System.err.println("No initial link provided, exiting");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        JcefLauncher jcefLauncher = new JcefLauncher(args[0]);
        jcefLauncher.launch();
    }
}
```

## Config files :-

**reflect-config.json :-**

```
[
{
  "name":"java.awt.SequencedEvent"
},
{
  "name":"java.awt.event.KeyEvent",
  "fields":[{"name":"VK_CONTEXT_MENU"}, {"name":"VK_F10"}]
},
{
  "name":"java.sql.Date"
},
{
  "name":"java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean",
  "fields":[{"name":"value"}]
},
{
  "name":"javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI",
  "methods":[{"name":"createUI","parameterTypes":["javax.swing.JComponent"] }]
},
{
  "name":"javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalRootPaneUI",
  "methods":[{"name":"createUI","parameterTypes":["javax.swing.JComponent"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.cef.browser.CefBrowserWr$3",
  "methods":[{"name":"coalesceEvents","parameterTypes":["java.awt.AWTEvent","java.awt.AWTEvent"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.example.SingletonDevTools",
  "methods":[{"name":"coalesceEvents","parameterTypes":["java.awt.AWTEvent","java.awt.AWTEvent"] }]
},
{
  "name":"sun.java2d.marlin.DMarlinRenderingEngine",
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
}
]
```

**resource-config.json :-**

```
{
  "resources":{
  "includes":[{
    "pattern":"\\Qbuild_meta.json\\E"
  }, {
    "pattern":"\\Qjcef-natives-linux-amd64-jcef-37f25dc+cef-116.0.19+gc6a20bc+chromium-116.0.5845.141.tar.gz\\E"
  }]},
  "bundles":[{
    "name":"com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.basic.resources.basic",
    "classNames":["com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.basic.resources.basic"]
  }, {
    "name":"com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources.metal",
    "classNames":["com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources.metal"]
  }, {
    "name":"sun.awt.resources.awt",
    "classNames":["sun.awt.resources.awt"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Build time warnings mean that the two methods are listed in `reflect-config.json` but not present in class files. Run time errors suggest that the classes they mention were not configured for reflective access, which seems indeed the case, as they are missing in `reflect-config.json`. They might be missing due to a bug in the agent, or because this particular code path was not executed during agent run.